# Limit in previous version of WM and DiscreteLimit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I find this limit (where $n$ is an integer number) in WM v 12.2:
$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sin^2(\pi\,\sqrt{n^2+n})$?

I mean, it's clear that it equals to one. Versions 9 and below easily produced the correct answer.
Now in v12.2 I've a lot of problems finding the same limit. Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Well correct me if i'm wrong, but its not clearly zero. It's actually one. First: this is what you can guess numerically. Second, you'll see that `Sqrt[n^2+n]` is growing asymptotically like `n+1/2`. See `Limit[Sqrt[n^2+n]-n,n->Infinity]` giving `1/2`. Thus we can pull the limit into the sine squared and get asymptotically `Sin[Pi*(n+1/2)]^2` giving one, as seen numerically too. Did I do something wrong? Btw. although it does not give a result here, `DiscreteLimit` is Mathematicas function for Limits over integers.

Comment: Sorry, sure it's one. Of course. Mea kulpa. But the problem is that `DiscreteLimit` does not produce this answer.

Comment: DiscreteLimit works finally in 13.2!!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in 12.2 as follows.

```
DiscreteAsymptotic[Sin[Pi*Sqrt[n^2 + n]]^2, n -> Infinity]
```

> `1`

Comment: Thank you, that's it!

Comment: In 13.1 `DiscreteLimit[Sin[Pi*Sqrt[n^2 + n]]^2, n -> Infinity]` is still unevaluated.

Comment: But it 13.2 it works!!! Strange, but cloud is now much faster...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is not equal to one if it is over Reals:

```
Asymptotics`ClassicLimit[Sin[Pi*Sqrt[n^2 + n]]^2, n -> Infinity]
```

prints Interval[{0, 1}]. While

```
Asymptotics`ClassicLimit[Sin[Pi*Sqrt[n^2 + n]]^2, n -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
```

does indeed print one. That is what versions 11.2 and below were using.

I suppose that is like one of those examples in DiscreteLimit[] documentation, after all "integers only" is far from the same as "all reals" limit.

(We cannot use modern Limit to solve this, since it does not allow any Assume[] or Assumptions if it is on the variable we are limiting.)

**Edit:**

In 13.2 it finally works!

```
DiscreteLimit[Sin[Pi*Sqrt[n^2 + n]]^2, n -> Infinity]
```

prints 1.

Comment: You open an opened door.

Comment: So you do not agree the result over reals is not just 1 number, but dense interval (well, in common sense limit does not exist)?

Comment: @user64494 This works now, did you notice?