# Why does Mathematica not recognize a convergent series?

Tags: bugs, summation, sum

**Bug introduced in 12.1, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

In one of my program run on Wolfram Cloud I run the command:

```
 Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k+1),{k,0,Infinity}]
```

and got the response

```
  Sum: Sum does not converge
```

This is very strange because the series obviously converges to $\frac\pi4+\frac{\log2}2$.

I have checked that the terms are correct running:

```
  Table[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k+1),{k,0,20}]
```

What is the reason for the problem? I run the same code several years ago without any issue.

**UPDATE:**
As pointed out by Roman the reason of the problem is most probably the usage of the `Floor` function. What is wrong with this?

Comment: `Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1), {k, 0, Infinity}, 
 Regularization -> "Abel"]`

Comment: I think because it is oscillating, it does not converge. Here is illustration: `data = Table[{k, (-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1)}, {k, 0, 300}];
data = Table[{data[[k, 1]], Total[data[[1 ;; k]][[All, 2]]]}, {k, 1, Length@data}];
p = ListLinePlot[data];
Show[p, Plot[Pi/4 + Log[2]/2, {x, 0, Length[data]},   PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> All]` screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufpaA.png)  so on average it does converge, but because it never settles due to +-, it is considered not to converge?

Comment: @Nasser The `Sum[(-1)^k/(k + 1), {k, 0, Infinity}` is computed fast and correct.

Comment: @Syed Thank you  very much! I remember I successfully computed the same sum several years ago without any additional options. What has changed?

Comment: You will have to wait for a knowledgeable answer from a mathematician. Things change (for the better mostly) between versions.

Comment: @Syed I assume you mean: mathematician = developer of Mathematca. :)

Comment: Series is not an infinite sum.

Comment: @user64494 Do you mean there is a special command for computing series?

Comment: @drer:  What I  mean is stated, for example, [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Series.html).

Comment: @user64494 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)

Comment: @drer: Wiki sometimes is too  lightweight in contrast to other encyclopedias. Also see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Series).

Comment: @user64494 From your reference I conclude that another word for series is infinite sum and I am quite sure that a lot of mathematicians use both terms interchangably.

Comment: @drer: Sorry, I find "infinite sum" only in the historic remarks to the article in Encyclopedia of Mathematics. You words are only wishful thinking .

Comment: Reported as a bug. This appears to have regressed beginning with version 12.1.

Comment: To clarify (or confound) nomenclature, a power series is an infinite sum. The result from Mathematica's `Series function is not.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Could you tell more about the bug? Is it indeed caused by the factor `(-1)^Floor [k/2]`?

Comment: It has something to do with Floor being in the input. Beyond that I don’t really know the specifics. The change was not arbitrary though; it came about in the process of fixing a bug.

Comment: @drer Series is not an infinite sum, because there is no such thing as infinite summation. The operation defined in school MUST BE FINITE. By definition, series is a sequence of partial sums of another sequence. That way limit is the "sum" of "infinite summation" operation. Infinite summation is sometimes talking about regularization, but there are many types of that, not only the standard Series way.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников It was already clarified in comments that the function `Sum` with an `Infinity` as limit of summation and no other additional options means computing series.

Answer (score 8):

I suggested this to another answer and is a nifty little trick in many/enough/whateverwordworksbestforeachoneofus situations.

Do the sum to a point and take the limit that it goes to infinity in the following manner:

```
Limit[Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1), {k, 0, xx}], {xx -> Infinity}]
```

to get

> ```
> 1/4 (π + Log[4])
> ```

P.S: taking the comments of a particular user into consideration, even though perhaps I should not, I am acknowledging that there is another answer similar to this one written by @user64494 and prior to mine that I had not seen.

As I explained in the comments I had not checked the submitted answer.

This can be understood since a week ago I suggested this approach to another question.

P.S 2: even with the previous phrasing it was clear how the answers were written, but some people are too uptight about minor things.

P.S 3: let's see if the other person will decide to appropriately cite, something that I highly doubt

Comment: This is a very interesting observation. I assumed however that this should be a normal way for `Mathematica` to treat the sums with `Infinity` as a summation limit.

Comment: @drer I am not familiar with the inner workings of `Sum`. sorry

Comment: This is by definition of series how it should work. @DanielLichtblau has identified the problem as a bug.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников without the use of @ it's difficult to understand to whom you are referring. Also, you wrote `why would you use DiscreteLimit` and then say `DiscreteLimit must be used` so it's, also, difficult to understand what you meant to say to begin with.

Comment: @bmf  I would assume that Валерий objects the usage of `Limit`.

Comment: @drer I imagined that, I just wanted to be sure. Also, I am not sure who deleted the other comments without leaving any justification...

Comment: @drer Yep. A typo. Why would you use a Limit? That is wrong, DiscreteLimit must be used instead. By definition sum of the series is limit of a sequence of partial sums of another sequence.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Could you give an example of `Limit` and `DiscreteLimit` working different for partial sums of a **convergent series**?

Comment: @drer E.g. Limit[Sin[Pi*Sqrt[n^2 + n]]^2, n -> Infinity]  does not exist, but the sequence limit does. The magic here we only consider points at x = 1, 2, 3, 4..., what that means is that if it oscillates the sequence limit does exist, but function limit does not exist. I hope you know how to define the series from its general partial sum. This was an example here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261428/82985

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Probably you did not understand me. I asked for an example where `Limit` gives a finite result but the result is incorrect, so that `DiscreteLimit` is needed.

Comment: @drer but if DiscreteLimit gives you limit does not exist that means the series does not converge. E.g. lets take basic 1 + 1 - 1 + 1-..., its partial sum sequence is 2, 1, 2, 1... and because you can extract two subsequences with limit 2 and limit 1, the limit of the sequence does not exist. Series does not converge. So using Limit will give you a wrong answer about convergence.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников I claim that if `Limit` gives a finite result for a series then `DiscreteLimit` will give for the series the same result. Could you give a counterexample? If not - can you tell us what are in this case the advantages of `DiscreteLimit`? Is it faster than the `Limit`?

Comment: @drer Yes, that is true. *Finite* limit of a function implies same limit of sequence, but not vice versa. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4221753/756502

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Ok, in this case the `Limit` gives the finite result, so that `DiscreteLimit` does not bring any new information for answering my question.

Comment: @drer Yes, correct.

Answer (score 7):

The explicit sum (without `Floor` magic) works fine:

```
Sum[1/(4 k + 1) + 1/(4 k + 2) - 1/(4 k + 3) - 1/(4 k + 4), {k, 0, ∞}]
(*    1/4 (π + Log[4])    *)
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150105/discussion-on-answer-by-roman-why-does-mathematica-not-recognize-a-convergent-se); please do not continue the discussion here.**

Answer (score 6):

```
InverseZTransform[ZTransform[(-1)^(Floor[k/2]), k, z], z, k] // FullSimplify
```

> $\cos \left(\frac{k \pi }{2}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{k \pi }{2}\right)$

```
Sum[(Cos[k π/2] + Sin[k π/2])/(k + 1), {k, 0, Infinity}] // FullSimplify
```

> $\frac{1}{4} (\pi +\log (4))$

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround in 13.3.1 on Windows 10. We find a partial sum

```
Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1), {k, 0, n}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

> `1/4 (\[Pi] +  Log[4] - (-1)^Floor[(1 + n)/2] PolyGamma[0, 1 + n/4] + (-1)^ Floor[(1 + n)/2] PolyGamma[0, (2 + n)/4] - (-1)^ Floor[n/2] PolyGamma[0, (3 + n)/4] + (-1)^ Floor[n/2] PolyGamma[0, (5 + n)/4])`

and then its limit as $n\to\infty$

```
DiscreteLimit[%, n -> Infinity]
```

> `1/4 (\[Pi] + Log[4])`

The latest execution takes on my comp approximately 100s.

Comment: The key part here, BTW, is the use of DiscreteLimit, as that is the limit of the sequence which is different from the limit of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Break the sum into its parts, e.g.,

```
Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1), {k, 0, Infinity, 2}] +
 Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1), {k, 1, Infinity, 2}]

(* π/4 + Log[2]/2 *)
```

Comment: The series does not absolutely converge. Therefore, such a split is not grounded (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence)).

Comment: BTW, `Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1), {k, 0, Infinity, 3}] + 
 Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1), {k, 1, Infinity, 3}] + 
 Sum[(-1)^(Floor[k/2])/(k + 1), {k, 2, Infinity, 3}]` outputs "Sum::div: Sum does not converge".

Comment: Yes, this would need justification. One way to reason is that it is a difference of two absolutely convergent subsequences obtained by a very minor change to the grouping by @Roman.

Comment: @DanielLichblau: Can you ground your empty words by theorems?

Comment: @user64494 Both series converge according to the Leibniz test for alternating series, so the split into these two series looks fine.

Comment: @mickep: I prefer theorems over empty words "looks fine",

Comment: @user64494 Theorem: the sum of two convergent series is convergent. Theorem: if a(k) is alternating and their absolute values converges monotonically to 0, the series with terms a(k) converges. Combine these two.

Comment: @mickep: See [the exact theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Absolutely_Convergent_Series).

Comment: @user64494 Not relevant since we do not have absolute convergent series here.

Comment: @mickep: I repeat the first comment of me ''The series does not absolutely converge. Therefore, such a split is not grounded (see Wiki)".

Comment: You cannot group the series that you do not yet know convergence of. (Sure, grouping of convergent series is only convergent.) Though, were the grouping divergent the original series is only divergent, yes.

Comment: This is very interesting observation! From this one could assume that it is the Dirichlet's test (or some of its generalizations), which is wrongly implemented in `Sum`.

Comment: Not here to teach you the math, @user64494. Your hint/outline is to group terms in pairs, get two series with strictly positive terms and O(1/n^2) behavior, use uniform convergence theorems to combine them. Your job to fill in the details, not mine.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau BTW, I did propose such a test with grouping and if you get divergent series, the original series is divergent.