# Find closed-form solution of this problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Would *Mathematica* be able to solve for the closed-form solution to the following type of problem?

[image]

> For $i\in\{0,1,2,...\}$ we have that$$C_{3*i+1}=C\\C_{3*i+2}=-C\\C_{3*i+3}=C$$Assume $r\gt0$. What is the closed form solution for$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\dfrac{C_i}{(1+r)^i}?$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 c*Sum[1/(1+r)^(3*i - 2) - 1/(1+r)^(3*i - 1) + 1/(1+r)^(3*i), {i, 1, Infinity}]
 (* c (1 + r + r^2))/(r (3 + 3 r + r^2) *)
```

Comment: First, the grouping `1/(1+r)^(3*i - 2) - 1/(1+r)^(3*i - 1) + 1/(1+r)^(3*i)` is made by hand, not with MMA. Second,  that grouping should be grounded (see a related [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293501/why-does-mathematica-not-recognize-a-convergent-series)). In the case under consideration the series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done as follows. First, we find an explicit formula for the coefficients by (`c` is used instead of `C` because capital letters are often reserved in WL.)

```
FindSequenceFunction[{c, -c, c, c, -c, c, c, -c, c}, i]
```

> `1/3 c (1 + E^(2/3 I (-3 + i) \[Pi]) + E^(4/3 I (-3 + i) \[Pi])) -  1/3 c (1 + E^(2/3 I (-2 + i) \[Pi]) + E^(4/3 I (-2 + i) \[Pi])) +  1/3 c (1 + E^(2/3 I (-1 + i) \[Pi]) + E^(4/3 I (-1 + i) \[Pi]))`

Second, we find the sum of the series by

```
Sum[(1/3 c (1 + E^(2/3 I (-3 + i) \[Pi]) + E^(
    4/3 I (-3 + i) \[Pi])) - 
 1/3 c (1 + E^(2/3 I (-2 + i) \[Pi]) + E^(
    4/3 I (-2 + i) \[Pi])) + 
 1/3 c (1 + E^(2/3 I (-1 + i) \[Pi]) + E^(
    4/3 I (-1 + i) \[Pi])))/(1 + r)^i, {i, 1, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> r > 0] // FullSimplify
```

> `(c (1 + r + r^2))/(r (3 + r (3 + r)))`

Addition. Simpler

```
Sum[Piecewise[{{c, Mod[i, 3] == 1}, {-c, Mod[i, 3] == 2},
{c,  Mod[i, 3] == 0}}]/(1 + r)^i, {i, 1, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> r > 0]
```

> `(c (1 + r + r^2))/(r (3 + 3 r + r^2))`